# How to insert a flyspell hook on Magit via `use-package` declaration?

Tags: magit, hooks, use-package, flyspell

I am rewriting my Emacs config file to fully use `use-package` and organize code. Currently, I have

```lisp
(use-package magit
  :custom
  (magit-display-buffer-function #'magit-display-buffer-same-window-except-diff-v1))

;; Flyspell
(add-hook 'git-commit-setup-hook 'git-commit-turn-on-flyspell)
```

It works but things are splited and they could be together. When I am writing commit messages, flyspell is activated and I can easily see grammar mistakes.

I tried to bring everything together in one s-expression with:

```lisp
;; Magit configuration
(use-package magit
  :custom
  (magit-display-buffer-function #'magit-display-buffer-same-window-except-diff-v1)
  :hook ((git-commit-setup-hook . git-commit-turn-on-flyspell)))
```

Unfortunately, it *does not* work. How can I fix this?

Thanks.

Comment: I suggest setting `use-package-hook-name-suffix` to `nil` for a very simple reason: that way you can still put the cursor on top of any symbol that corresponds to a hook and inspect it with `C-h o`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is from the README of [use-package](https://github.com/jwiegley/use-package#hooks)

> When using :hook omit the "-hook" suffix if you specify the hook explicitly, as this is appended by default. For example the following code will not work as it attempts to add to the prog-mode-hook-hook which does not exist:

```lisp
;; DOES NOT WORK
(use-package ace-jump-mode
  :hook (prog-mode-hook . ace-jump-mode))
```

> If you do not like this behaviour, set use-package-hook-name-suffix to nil. By default the value of this variable is "-hook".

Comment: It works now, thanks. Following your suggestion, I just did a minor tweak: `(use-package magit
  :custom
  (magit-display-buffer-function #'magit-display-buffer-same-window-except-diff-v1)
  :hook ((git-commit-setup . git-commit-turn-on-flyspell)))`